# Match sting in files and calculate total number of occurance

Tags: perl, file

I have two file one is keyword file other as search file

search.txt

```
play       dream
dream      play
dream
```

keyword.txt

```
play
dream
```

I want to calculate total occurrences for play and dream, such as `play= 2, dream =3`

Code i have tried so far is:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#Lexical variable for filehandle is preferred, and always error check opens.
open my $keywords,    '<', 'keyword.txt' or die "Can't open keywords: $!";
open my $search_file, '<', 'search.txt'   or die "Can't open search file: $!";
my $count=0;
my $keyword_or = join '|', map {chomp;qr/\Q$_\E/} <$keywords>;
my $regex = qr|\b($keyword_or)\b|;

while (<$search_file>)
{

    while (/$regex/g)
    {
    $count++;
        print "$.: $1\n";
        print($count);


    }
}
```

But it is counting total occurrences for i.e 5

Comment: Use commas and full stops. Please.

Comment: no there are two files one is having keywords such as dream and play while other is having multiple lines having dream and play. what we need is to take keyword from 1st file and find total no. of keyword occurences in other

Comment: so play=2 and dream=3 this should be output expected

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash to count the no of occurrences of the words. Keywords as key of hash and count as value.

```
while (/$regex/g){
    $hash{$1}++;
}

# print the hash    
foreach(keys %hash){
    print "$_ : $hash{$_}\n";
}
```

Comment: `%` is sigil used to declare a hash in Perl. Hashes are data type in Perl,  for more info you should check [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)